# Circle collider wheels push through polygon collider car chassis

Tags: unity, collision-detection, rigidbody, collider, joints

I'm trying to create a simple vehicle and make it run on a terrain (from sprites + `PolygonCollider2D`).

- I imported a chassis sprite with `Rigidbody2D` and `PolygonCollider2D`.
- Then I imported a wheel with `Rigidbody2D` and `CircleCollider2D`.
- I joined them with a `DistanceJoint2D` in the wheels and added the chassis as the parent.

But the wheel collides with terrain but not with the car. And you guys can also see the car/chassis collides with the terrain.

[image: circle collider 2d sometime works, sometime it doesn't]

How can I solve this?

Comment: It looks to me like you want a Fixed Joint for that situation, not a Distance Joint. You've also left the "Enable Collision" box unchecked on your joint - was that deliberate?

Comment: @DMGregory **with fixed joint** *chassis/car doesn't move a bit, cause then the wheel doesn't rotate.* and I wasn't sure about the enable-joint, so i left it default.

Comment: Then perhaps try a Hinge Joint?

Comment: @DMGregory thats working, but can you tell please why is that ??

Comment: Why use a joint designed for rotating objects around a pivot when you want to implement an object that rotates around a pivot? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer below.

Comment: @DMGregory your solution worked, shouldn't you be the one who posting answer, as your solution work. And I'm supposed to mark as correct and upvote ??

Comment: You have access to your project, and can share screenshots that show how you set it up. I don't have those. And I don't really need more rep. 